# App cannot be verified on ios 9

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

I am running testing of an app on my iphone 6s running ios 9. Given the new feature introduced in ios 9 and xcode 7 release, I was able to test run my app on ios devices without getting the $99 membership.

Everything used to work fine. I trusted the developer ID and run the app without any issue until the last change I made to the code. Then I can see the app was installed but said "Not Verified". When I went to Settings->General->Profile, I can see under the developer's profile there is a button called "Verify App". However when I click the button nothing happened. The app remains unverified and cannot be verified thus cannot run.

Anyone experienced something similar? Any idea on how to fix the issue?

===========================================================
Update upon the issue disappear:

What I did is logging into apple developer website with the username. After logging in, the apps can be verified with no problem.

Comment: I would guess its Apple cracking down on not having a proper membership.

Comment: Having similar issue.. Specific to iOS 9

Comment: Why on earth was this edited to remove the other answers?

Comment: Same Problem here. Initially I thought there is a problem with my paid account provisioning profiles but nothing helped. I tried looking into network logs when the "Verify App" makes a call to Apple server . Looks like that service is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when establishing trust for the app developer's certificate connections to https://ppq.apple.com is made.

The above site had an invalid certificate which prevented the verification process.

As of now the issue has been resolved.

Comment: This issue is still occurring for me, is there a cache I should clear?

Comment: I am also having same issue.

Comment: I think it's having the same issues, is there a way to verify this?

Comment: Working again...weird.

Answer (score 0):

Delete you app from the Settings>General>Profile> Developer APP> Then delete your app from there.
Come out of the settings and reinstall your app fro Xcode, again open Settings>General>Profile> Tap on Profile> Now you will see a button with blue text "Trust ", tap on it and you are done.

It works for me.

Please ask if you still have issue, happy coding, CHEERS!!!